# Github API -- request for diff in repository with 1 commit 404s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, github, github-api

I'm trying to allow users of my app to pull git diffs from their repositories using the api. It's working great, except for one weird case that feels like a bug.

Basically, if the repo has more than one commit, everything works smoothly. However, if there's only the one initial commit, the API returns a 404 error, which brings down the view on my page. This is weird, because you can view "Diffs", or at least files changed in the most recent (first) commit, on the github page.

Moreover, I can fetch the diff in another format (not ideal) if I don't specify the format I accept.

Take, for example, my friend's repo (this is using Rails's RestClient instead of curl). In her repo, which has just one commit, this 404s:

```
# Replaced fake values (per request) with symbols. Don't feel comfortable sharing her GH info without asking.
RestClient.get("https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:sha", accept: 'application/vnd.github.diff')
```

But this (without the accept) returns the commit, just not in diff format:

```
RestClient.get("https://api.github.com/repos/:ownder/:repo/commits/:sha")
```

If I were to pull diffs from other repos of hers with more than one commit, using

```
RestClient.get("https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:sha", accept: 'application/vnd.github.diff')
```

works great. Am I doing something wrong? What's up with this?

Comment: Please don't use fake values. They can be misleading or deceptive. Sometimes both.